# Stylesheets not applied to webpage MEAN stack

Tags: javascript, html, css, mean-stack, hogan.js

I am trying to make a website using the MEAN stack with hogan instead of jade, but my stylesheet isn't applying to my webpage. My directory looks like this (not showing the module files since they are the originals and I did not edit them):

```
web_folder
 - bin
    - www
 - node_modules
    - body-parser
    - cookie-parser
    - debug
    - express
    - hjs
    - less-middleware
    - morgan
    - serve-favicon
 - public
    - images
    - javascripts
    - stylesheets
       - style.css
       - style.less
    - favicon.ico
 - routes
    - index.js
    - users.js
 - views
    - error.hjs
    - index.hjs
 - app.js
 - package.json
```

My app.js includes these lines which I thought was all that was needed to apply the stylesheets:

```
var app = express();

app.use(require('less-middleware')(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

The stylesheet still does not apply to the webpage. And if I go to localhost:3000/stylesheets/style.css it displays this error:

```
Unrecognised input

Error
    at new Parser (C:\Users\WScott\Desktop\Programming\meanJS\exp2015\node_modules\less-middleware\node_modules\less\lib\less\parser.js:333:27)
    at render (C:\Users\WScott\Desktop\Programming\meanJS\exp2015\node_modules\less-middleware\lib\middleware.js:153:18)
    at C:\Users\WScott\Desktop\Programming\meanJS\exp2015\node_modules\less-middleware\lib\middleware.js:245:13
    at fs.js:336:14
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:99:15)
```

I'm new to the MEAN stack and I can't find a solution online. If needed I can post more of my app.js or the code of the other files

**EDIT: Completely reformatted question including relevant code snippets and my directory**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK there looks like there is an error when its trying to parse your LESS file.

The error output was trying to show you the contents of the line in your less file where the error occurred, but it looks likes that line had no contents.

You could try running your less file through a [online-less-compiler](http://winless.org/online-less-compiler)  to check its has a valid format.

To see if that helps you locate the issues with the format of the file.

Comment: Running through that repeated the error but didn't give a line number or anything, so it wasn't much help. I found out the problem was I tried to use an html comment in a css file. I really wish all languages used the same implementation for comments... Thank you for your time and help.